# How to check array inputs are positive if in for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, input

I am attempting to use this code to ensure if a negative value is entered, it'll be recognised as an invalid input and require the user to retype the scores.

I am unsure why this isn't being found, though I do believe it may have to do with my array indexing. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double quiz_1(){
    int test_scores[3];
    double result;

    printf("Please Enter The Students Test Score (e.g. 85 65 75): ");

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof test_scores / sizeof test_scores[0]); i++) {
        if(scanf("%d", &test_scores[i]) < 0){
             printf("\nInvalid Input\nPlease Enter The Students Test Score (e.g. 85 65 75): ");
             i = 0;
         }
    }

result = (test_scores[0] * 0.2) + (test_scores[1] * 0.3) + (test_scores[2] * 0.5);

printf("\nThe Student's Final Grade is %.2f", result);

return 0;

}

int main() {
   quiz_1();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: On success, the scanf function returns the number of items successfully filled (it will likely be 1 in your case). It doesn't return the integer value of the first item that it fills.

Comment: Note that resetting `i` to `0` in the `if` means it is incremented after the loop to `i`, so the next cycle starts with `i == 1`.  You probably need to use `i = -1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. I think you're meaning to test `if (test_scores[i] < 0)`.

Comment: So, i've changed my code to `if(test_scores[i] < 0)` and kept the `scanf("%d", &test_scores[i]);` above it. It works the first time but it doesn't utilise the validation code after attempting to do the negative number again

Comment: My apologies. It's due to `i = 0` and it should be `i = -1` like Jonathan said. Thank you